# Table header text transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used transform: rotate(270deg) for table header, but since names in that header are not equal ( not even close) it looks ugly, so I have to make every column equal width. Some text in table header is made with 2 or 3 words, some are single word.

Here it is how it looks like: http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/9527/tbl.png

All I want, is that every column has same width, no matter how long name in header is, and name put to be in 2 rows max.

Edit:
Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/SvAk8/

```
.header {


-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);  
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
-o-transform: rotate(27deg);
transform: rotate(270deg); 
white-space: pre-line; 
width: 50px;
height: 180px; /* to be adjusted: column is not always tall enough for text */
margin: 0 -80px;
vertical-align: middle;
```

}

Comment: I can't help you without seeing relevant code.  Please provide all the HTML and CSS to demonstrate the problem, but without anything irrelevant.

Comment: Have you defined the width and height of each `<td>` in the header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this specification:

```
table { width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; }
```

`table-layout: fixed;` does this:

> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col
>   elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in
>   subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

and requires a specified width. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/table-layout for more.

Answer (score 1):

That is the best what I got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  (function () {
    var maxW = 0,
      maxH = 0;

    $("td.header").each(function () {

      $cell = $(this);

      $dummyDiv = $("<div></div>", {
        text: $cell.text()
      });

      // Replaces the original text for a DummyDiv to figureout the cell size before the rotation
      $cell.html($dummyDiv);

      if ($cell.width() > maxW) maxW = $cell.width();
      if ($cell.height() > maxH) maxH = $cell.height();
    });

    $("td.header").each(function () {
      // Applies the rotation and then the size previosly calculated
      $(this)
        .addClass("rotate")
        .width(maxH + 10)
        .height(maxW + 10);
    });
  })();
});
```

You can see a live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrr3G/

I hope that can help :)

Answer (score -1):

OK! I made a reserch and it seems that browsers won't calculate dimansions after transform.

[Rotate Text as Headers in a table (cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999523/rotate-text-as-headers-in-a-table-cross-browser)

I think you got only one option and its: javascript;

find yourself a good line height and after page load resize the  width.